# Bash script: allow change of "environment/identity"

Tags: linux, bash

I came across this problem now several times and I would like to find a way to automate/script this things that involves a change of identity or environment (I am not sure how to call that precisely).

An easy example would be a script where a part has to be executed with `su`. (`make install` for instance). To achieve this one could use `sudo`. However there are other environment changes that do not have such an escape solution. Probably well known is the python virtualenv where one could easily imagine a script like

```
source virtEnv/bin/activate
python myScript.py
```

or simply a script that invokes `screen`. Now I am compiling gstreamer which I would like to automate in a script, because I will have to deploy this installation in several other computers later

```
for i in gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-python gnonlin gst-ffmpeg 
do
   gst-head
   cd ./$i
   git checkout tags/1.1.1
   ./autogen.sh
   make -j7
   exit
done
```

Where `gst-head` is the `gst-uninstalled` script that loads a local pkg_config (if I am right) and puts me in a separate environment. If I put that in a script the script will stop its execution there and continues once I do `exit` from that environment.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem here is. Is `make` not executed? What does not work in the script you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

That "environment" where the script "puts you", is a new instance of your shell actually. And instead of simply calling gst-head without a parameter, you should pass the commands as arguments! Can you see this part in the script?

```
# if we got a command, run it, else start a shell
if test ! -z "$1";
then
  $@
  exit $?
fi
```

I think you should try to make use of it. 
BTW, if you want to start a shell at all costs, then you won't be able to interact with it unless you use expect, in some way (either a standalone expect script or embedded into a shell script).